# Is there a way to map Sitecore/System/Languages in Sitecore to Sitecore.Globalization.Languages using Glass mapper

Tags: glass-mapper

I am using `TDS` and was trying to map the `Glass mapper` to `Sitecore.Globalization.Languages`.

This requirement is for a Language dropdown with custom names for different regions.

Comment: Maybe adding a method to your Language GM type called "ToGlobalizationLanguage()" with simple logic to get language by name would be good enough?

Comment: Even I couldn't find a way to get that done using ORM directly.  I had to follow a similar method to achieve what I was looking for.